# WAP Push SMS in Symbian

Tags: sms, symbian, wap

I have managed to send out (and receive) binary SMSs, but what I want to accomplish is to send Access Point settings or bookmarks or Email settings etc. 
Currently I'm sending out messages like:

```
//udh=0605040B8423F0
//message=FD0601AE02056A0045C60C037777772E676F6F676C65...000101
    //udh
    iMessage->Des().Append(0x06);
    iMessage->Des().Append(0x05);
    iMessage->Des().Append(0x04);
    iMessage->Des().Append(0x0B);
    iMessage->Des().Append(0x84);
    iMessage->Des().Append(0x23);
    iMessage->Des().Append(0xF0);

    iMessage->Des().Append(0xFD);
    iMessage->Des().Append(0x06);
```

But they arrive in the same format and also arrive to the same port as normal SMSs. When I receive AP settings from operator, then it arrives to some different port and is shown correctly.

Comment: You don't mention how you are sending the SMS messages - the only way you can direct to a specific port is through an SMS socket (rather than via the Messaging APIs). Which are you using?

Comment: Ports are defined in UDH header.
But as I got response from Nokia - it' can't be done this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asked it also from Nokia and verdict was that I can't be done. :(

It can be done when phone is used as a modem and commands are sent from the PC.
If I could figure out the way how to emulate all that in phone, then it would be cool.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't do it with an SMS, just use the SMS as a trigger so an application installed on the phone knows to download the settings from a website.

In that application, use the messaging API to update email settings, the commsdb API to update APN settings, the webkit API to update bookmaks, all according to the data you just downloaded from the website.

Deployment becomes an issue and more development is required but that should do the job.

Comment: That's the point - there is no application on phone. I want to create new access point, so he can download my application (in case the phone doesn't have any AP yet.)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, WAP push requires a destination port of 2948 and (I think) a source port of 9200  and the content is a WBXML formatted command/request sent as 8 bit data.

This link shows how to set the ports using Symbian:

http://www.newlc.com/Sending-a-message-from-Symbian-C.html

Comment: The prots are declared in the header - udh=0605040B8423F0

Answer (score 0):

I use aspsms broker service. They have this sample for wap push: http://www.aspsms.com/examples/asp/wappush.asp

It might work or not... try at your own risk :)